# cp a file from within a volume to another location in the container - just use a volume, add Dockerfile? Or can I do it within compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file in my working directory. I don't have a Dockerfile (Yet, I'm unsure if I need one?). Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  ide-rstudio:
    image: rocker/verse:latest
    ports:
      - 8787:8787
      - 3838:3838
    environment:
      PASSWORD: test
      ROOT: "TRUE"
      ADD: "shiny"
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECTS_DIR}/Zen:/home/rstudio/Projects
```

When I run this, a new container runs as expected. In the volume I have a file `/Zen/ide-rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json`. I would like to add `rstudio-prefs.json` into my container at `/home/rstudio/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json`. I CAN already do this by using a volume and adding this line to my docker-compose volumes:

```
volumes:
  - ${PROJECTS_DIR}/Zen:/home/rstudio/Projects
  - ${PROJECTS_DIR}/Zen/ide-rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json:/home/rstudio/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json
```

My question is, if after adding the volume in the first line `${PROJECTS_DIR}/Zen:/home/rstudio/Projects` the file `rstudio-prefs.json` already exists in the container at `/home/rstudio/Projects/ide-rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json`. So, I would really just like to run the following shell command after the container is started `cp /home/rstudio/Projects/ide-rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json /home/rstudio/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json`.

Is it possible to run a shell command within a service using docker-compose? Or, must I now create a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `volumes:` approach you show.  This works automatically and doesn't require any user intervention.  There's no harm to having a second copy of the file in the container, especially a small configuration file.

You *could* in principle run [`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) after the container starts up.  There are a couple of problems with doing this.  If the config file is read by the container's main process, that will happen before you have an opportunity to run debug commands like this.  You'll need to remember to repeat this command every time you restart the container.  If you wind up in a cluster environment like Kubernetes, you'll need to remember to do this on every replica of the container, and arrange for it to happen if the cluster restarts the container without your knowledge (for example, if a node fails).

If you want this to happen reliably, as a shell command, then you need to write an entrypoint wrapper script.  This runs whatever first-time setup you need and then `exec`s the image's original entrypoint.  This is easier to do reproducibly with a custom Dockerfile, and requires some knowledge of the image's detailed setup.

The one-line `volumes:` to inject the same file a second time is much easier.